# How can I set 'min' attribute for a Textfield type date in Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

It seems it is possible to set the min attribution for [Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) type date. Is it also possible to set the min attribution for the [Textfield](https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/) type date in Material UI?
Seems like the code below doesn't work well.

```
    <TextField
      id="date"
      label="Date"
      type="date"
      min="2020-08-10"
      defaultValue="mm-dd-yyyy"
      onChange={props.handleTime}
      className={classes.date}
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass `min` and `max` values using `inputProps` parameter:

```
      <TextField
        id="date"
        label="Date"
        type="date"
        defaultValue="2020-08-15"
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true,
        }}
        inputProps={{
          min: "2020-08-10",
          max: "2020-08-20"
        }}
      />
```