# How to disable dates in react-admin DateInput

Tags: react-admin

Is there any attribute we can use to disable future dates in react admin Date Input filter.

```
<DateInput
source="name"
label="name"
alwaysOn
validate={getValidate(props)}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React-admin uses html5 date input under the hood, so you can use the min and max attributes for that.
See [Restrict future dates in HTML5 date input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671407/restrict-future-dates-in-html5-date-input).

Comment: I applied max attribute in DateInput, while rendering it's getting applied in div instead of the input tag

Comment: My mistake, you have to use the inputProps props to pass the props directly to the input. react-admin DateInput uses material-ui TextField see https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63379460/how-can-i-set-min-attribute-for-a-textfield-type-date-in-material-ui

Answer (score 0):

we can pass as prop the property inputProps and send min and max

```
 <DateTimeInput
   source="end_time"
   label="end_time"
   fullWidth
   inputProps={{
     min: '2022-04-22T00:00',
     max: '2022-04-28T00:00',
    }}
 />
```